# Converting non-redundant data to redundant data in files with different names

Tags: unix

I have two sets of files .txt and .xml and there are various versions.
The file names and their contents are as follows:-

```
filenameXYZ_v1.0.txt
apple
filenameXYZ_v2.0.txt
apple
filenameXYZ_v3.0.txt 
orange
filenameXYZ_v4.0.txt 
orange
```

.................................

```
filenameXYZ_v1.0.xml
"Data of v1.0 and v2.0"
filenameXYZ_v2.0.xml
"Junk"
filenameXYZ_v3.0.xml
"Data of v3.0 and v4.0"
filenameXYZ_v4.0.xml
"Junk"
```

The data in the xml files are non-redundant ie if their corresponding .txt files have the same contents then only one .xml file will have the real "Data" other versions will be filled with "Junk". I want to make the xml files redundant like:-

```
filenameXYZ_v1.0.xml
"Data of v1.0 and v2.0"
filenameXYZ_v2.0.xml
"Data of v1.0 and v2.0"
filenameXYZ_v3.0.xml
"Data of v3.0 and v4.0"
filenameXYZ_v4.0.xml
"Data of v3.0 and v4.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for file in filenameXYZ_v?.0.txt
do  if [ "$prefile" ] && cmp -s $file $prefile
    then    cp `basename $prefile txt`xml `basename $file txt`xml
    fi
    prefile=$file
done
```